# ColdFusion 9 - Error: Invalid list index 0

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I thought I had this one licked...
But I can't seem to get it tracked down...

Funny thing is - the list delete function works... And performs the desired task...
But I still get this error...

> Invalid list index 0. In function ListDeleteAt(list, index [, delimiters]), the value of index, 0, is not a valid as the first argument (this list has 12 elements). Valid indexes are in the range 1 through the number of elements in the list. 
> The error occurred on line 735.

Code below

```
      <cfset pwlist = "#add.pwlist#"> 

      <cfset curlist = "#add.pwlist#"> 
      <cfset ud = "#session.demshinuser_id#"> 

      <cfoutput> 
      #curlist#
      <br>
      <br>
      #pwlist#
      <br><br>
      #ud#<br> 

      <cfset newlist = ListDeleteAt(curlist, ListFind(pwlist,ud,","), ",")>  <-- Error Here

      #newlist# 
      </cfoutput>

      <cfquery name=Update DATASOURCE="#ds#">
        update shindates
        set 
        pwlist = '#newlist#'
        where shinid = '#shinid#'
      </cfquery>

      <cfif src is "cpwupc">
      <cflocation url="upc.cfm" addToken="no">
      </cfif>
      <cfif src is "hcpw">
      <cflocation url="list.cfm?typeid=#add.typeid#" addToken="no">
      </cfif>
```

Found on Goog - trying this too to check if it a bad list thing... and ud isn't in list in first place...

```
     <cfset pos = listfind(pwlist,ud)>
     <cfif pos>

        do list delete 

     <cfelse>

        error. element not found. do something else

     </cfif>
```

Comment: I also have code working too... <cfset newlist = ListDeleteAt( curlist, ListFind(userssigned,ud,","), ",")> - which has space - but not sure that space matters..

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You say "the list delete function works", but if you are getting an error when using it, then clearly ... it does not work. The error message seems pretty clear. The code is trying to delete an element that does not exist which needs to be handled in code. As you are already doing that in the last code block, ... **what is your actual question/issue**? (As an aside, there are several improvements you could make to the code, but first things first ...)

Comment: if you're getting list index 0 then your string is not found in your `listFind`

Comment: My bad - it was a listfind thing - I missed the checking for it... I have similar code that was checking... But I missed the checking on this one and couldn't figure it out...

Comment: For next time, best to put together an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (without any unrelated code like cflocation) *before* posting here. If you had put that together with the snippet you found on google, you probably would have discovered you already *had* the answer ;-)